# Enable Soft Asserts in Serenity - Cucumber JVM

Tags: junit, assertions, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

In Serenity-Cucumber execution, I am trying to insert Soft asserts in the Serenity Steps using the following command

```
StepEventBus.getEventBus().enableSoftAsserts();
```

This isn't showing any effective soft Assertion .

Where as when I do the same enableSoftAsserts() through the Step EventBus , in the Execution through Serenity-Junit , I am able to achieve the SoftAssertion, I mean Able to execute the Later Steps even a step fails in between.

Can you please let me know how to achive the same SoftAssertion behaviour in Serenity-Cucumber:JVM as that of Serenity-Junit.

Also, I am not using Serenity ScreenPlay, I am just calling enableSoftAsserts() method in the Before Method of Test of Junit.